# error: not enough arguments for method withColumn: Scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What am i doing wrong here? I am trying to explode the json column, it looks ok to me, but keep getting this error? Can someone help me please?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val yearname = baby_names.withColumn("data".explode($"data"))
.withColumn("year",$"data"(8))
.withColumn("name",$"data"(9))
.select("year","name")
```

*command-3936897808825418:4: error: not enough arguments for method withColumn: (colName: String, col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.
Unspecified value parameter col.
val yearname = baby_names.withColumn("data".explode($"data"))*

Comment: My bad, yes. that's right. typo , instead of . Thanks. Write it as an answer, let me accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean `withColumn("data",explode($"data"))` with a comma `,` separating the 2 arguments. That way it matches the profile:

```
def withColumn(colName: String, col: Column): DataFrame
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the third line  , I suggest to change it to:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
val yearname = baby_names.withColumn("data", F.explode(F.col("data")))
```